# Rails return JSON serialized attribute with_indifferent_access

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I previously had:

```
serialize :params, JSON
```

But this would return the JSON and convert hash key symbols to strings. I want to reference the hash using symbols, as is most common when working with hashes. I feed it symbols, Rails returns strings. To avoid this, I created my own getter/setter. The setter is simple enough (JSON encode), the getter is:

```
  def params
    read_attribute(:params) || JSON.parse(read_attribute(:params).to_json).with_indifferent_access
  end
```

I couldn't reference `params` directly because that would cause a loop, so I'm using `read_attribute`, and now my hash keys can be referenced with symbols or strings. However, this does not update the hash:

```
model.params.merge!(test: 'test')
puts model.params # => returns default params without merge
```

Which makes me think the hash is being referenced by copy.

My question is twofold. Can I extend active record JSON serialization to return indifferent access hash (or not convert symbols to strings), and still have hash work as above with merge? If not, what can I do to improve my getter so that `model.params.merge!` works?

I was hoping for something along the lines of (which works):

```
  def params_merge!(hash)
    write_attribute(:params, read_attribute(:params).merge(hash))
  end

  # usage: model.params_merge!(test: 'test')
```

Better yet, just get Rails to return a hash with indifferent access or not convert my symbols into strings! Appreciate any help.

Comment: `model.params.merge!(test: 'test').save` ?

Comment: No, I don't want to have to save to the database. This is mainly used for testing purposes for now. The only other workaround I've found is `model.params = model.params.merge(test: 'test')`.

Comment: I was hoping there might be some ruby magic, like a special method I can add for params, something like `params{}`.

Comment: `model.params[:test] = 'test'` by any chance?

Comment: variable assignment still works, as I illustrated with `model.params = ...`, it is `Hash.merge` I cannot perform directly on the attribute, even though it returns the updated hash.

Comment: yuck, sorry i think my answer is a bit aside of the question. If you don't need to persist, why not use a proxy class of your own instead of HashWithIndifferentAccess ? Reading on it would unserialize if needed, and any other operations would be performed on the original JSON.

Comment: @m_x I think that's a good idea. Dump hash, load with indifferent access.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

use the built-in `serialize` method :

```
class Whatever < ActiveRecord::Base
 serialize :params, HashWithIndifferentAccess
end
```

see [ActiveRecord::Base docs on serialization](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html#label-Saving+arrays%2C+hashes%2C+and+other+non-mappable+objects+in+text+columns) for more info.

Comment: This means I have to feed it a hash with indifferent access. I just want to return one. Thanks, though. This seems like the right direction.

Comment: yeah... i'm not sure where you're headed. I don't know any lib that has a `Json` object on which you can use `#merge!` (in ruby, any JSON is just a string...). As i said, you should roll your own proxy class.

Comment: That was what tripped me up! Serialising as JSON. Thanks for the pointer, I didn't realise Rails had so many serialize options.

Comment: Researched the same problem just last night... since you can pass any class to serialize that has `load` and `dump` methods, I just wrapped the JSON with my own class, `JSONWithSymbolizedNames`, passing in `symbolize_names:true`.

Comment: I having an error in Rails 4 when I initialise the attribute with a Hash and try to save the instance: `Attribute was supposed to be a ActiveSupport::HashWithIndifferentAccess, but was a Hash.`

Comment: @bimsapi I think would be nice is you provide an example of your solution as an answer. Please, _ping_ me if you do so.

Comment: @fguillen - posted... hope it helps. And apologies for misspelling your name first time around ;)

Comment: This doesn't work if the serialized value is a array of hashes

Comment: if the class doesn't respond to `load` and `dump` methods then `Coders::YAMLColumn` uses by default. So when you declare `HashWithIndifferentAccess` as a serializer, actually uses `YAMLColumn` serializer

Answer (score 8):

Posting comment as answer, per @fguillen's request... Caveat: I am not typically a Rubyist… so this may not be idiomatic or efficient. Functionally, it got me what I wanted. Seems to work in Rails 3.2 and 4.0...

In `application_helper.rb`:

```
module ApplicationHelper
  class JSONWithIndifferentAccess
    def self.load(str)
      obj = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(JSON.load(str))
      #...or simply: obj = JSON.load(str, nil, symbolize_names:true)
      obj.freeze #i also want it set all or nothing, not piecemeal; ymmv
      obj
    end
    def self.dump(obj)
      JSON.dump(obj)
    end
  end
end
```

In my model, I have a field called `rule_spec`, serialized into a `text` field:

```
serialize :rule_spec, ApplicationHelper::JSONWithIndifferentAccess
```

Ultimately, I realized I just wanted symbols, not indifferent access, but by tweaking the load method you can get either behavior.

Answer (score 7):

Using `HashWithIndifferentAccess` is great, but it still acts like a Hash, and it can only serialize as YAML in the database.

My preference, using Postgres 9.3 and higher, is to use the json column type in Postgres. This means that when the table is read, ActiveRecord will get a Hash directly from Postgres.

```
create_table "gadgets" do |t|
  t.json "info"
end
```

ActiveRecord `serialize` requires that you provide it a single class that is both responsible for reading/writing the data *and* serializing/deserializing it.

So you can create an object that does the job by inheriting from `HashWithIndifferentAccess`, or my preference, `Hashie::Mash`. Then you implement the serialization as the `dump` and `load` class methods.

```
class HashieMashStoredAsJson < Hashie::Mash
  def self.dump(obj)
    ActiveSupport::JSON.encode(obj.to_h)
  end


  def self.load(raw_hash)
    new(raw_hash || {}) 
  end
end
```

In your model, you can specify this class for serialization.

```
class Gadget < ActiveRecord::Base
  serialize :info, HashieMashStoredAsJson

  # This allows the field to be set as a Hash or anything compatible with it.
  def info=(new_value)
    self[:info] = HashieMashStoredAsJson.new new_value
  end
end
```

If you don't use the json column type in Postgres, the implementation changes slightly

Full code and documentation here: [using a JSON column type](https://gist.github.com/RobinDaugherty/5e7bc2a6e2369a29c77c) and [using a string column type](https://gist.github.com/RobinDaugherty/bafe6716b984f8bcc87e).

Answer (score 6):

I ended up using a variation on bimsapi's solution that you can use ***not only*** with simple un-nested JSON but *any* JSON.

Once this is loaded...

```
module JsonHelper

  class JsonWithIndifferentAccess
    def self.load(str)
      self.indifferent_access JSON.load(str)
    end

    def self.dump(obj)
      JSON.dump(obj)
    end

    private

      def self.indifferent_access(obj)
        if obj.is_a? Array
          obj.map!{|o| self.indifferent_access(o)}
        elsif obj.is_a? Hash
          obj.with_indifferent_access
        else
          obj
        end
      end
  end

end
```

then instead of calling

```
JSON.load(http_response)
```

you just call

```
JsonHelper::JsonWithIndifferentAccess.load(http_response)
```

Does the same thing but all the nested hashes are indifferent access.

Should serve you well but think a little before making it your default approach for all parsing as massive JSON payloads will add significant ruby operations on top of the native JSON parser which is optimised in C and more fully designed for performance.

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly the kind of thing I was just about to write if there wasn't an off the peg solution.

Comment: Just copied the class and used `serialize :params, JsonWithIndifferentAccess` and worked like a charm!